# Having problems getting information with the Graph API

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook Graph API to get information about users who logged in via Facebook.

At the beginning, I was using only one function and no errors occurred; But then, I added another function that uses Facebook API. From that moment, none of the functions works. Only when I remove the new function, the old one works again...

I guess the code will be much understandable than what I described above:

```
    function fb_login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {

            if (response.authResponse) {
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
                user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    user_email = response.email; //get user email

                            $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "http://*******/ajax.php",
                              data: { action: "login", id: user_id, email: user_email, first_name: response.first_name, last_name: response.last_name }
                            }).done(function( msg ) {
                              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                            });            
                });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'publish_actions,email,read_stream,publish_stream'
    });
}
```

The function above will work unless the function below exists.

```
function update_autopost(form)
{
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    var autopost_value = form.autopost.checked;

                    if(autopost_value == false)
                    {
                        autopost_value = "off";
                    }
                    else{
                        autopost_value = "on";
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://*********/ajax.php",
                      data: { action: "update", id: response.authResponse.userID, autopost: autopost_value }
                    }).done(function( msg ) {
                      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                    });            
        });
}
```

To be more detailed, after adding the second function, two things happens:

1. The first function stops working.
2. The second function is not able to get information from Facebook Graph API (for instance,  *response.authResponse.userID* doesn't work).

Comment: perhaps something wrong with `form.autopost.checked`

Comment: 1) check using your browser console for errors 2) check Pulkit comment 3) maybe the graph call in the second function didn't return a valid response and hence use the same validation as in the first: `if (response) {...your code here}`

Comment: oh `/me` doesn't return `response.authResponse`, try to test it in the JS [console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/). You should use something like `response.id`

Comment: I am getting this error (Chrome Console):
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined"

What does it mean?
I have also tried your suggestions, but it still does not work...

Comment: It means that the object that you are trying to access a property called `userID` on is in fact not an object, but “nothing”, which in JavaScript is called `undefined`. Calling `/me` does not give you an authResponse object, only FB.login/FB.getLoginStatus do.

Comment: well that's what i did and it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/idodoron11/cHd9s

Comment: Finally, I managed to solve it by myself. Thank you for trying to help me though :)